# Hydra game and quantum superposition

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory, intuition

[Goodstein's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) is not provable in Peano Arithmetic showed by Kirby and Harrington in 1982 [[Wolfram Mathworld]](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoodsteinSequence.html).

***Any reference of a "quantum" hydra game where a head can remain in a state of superposition?***

[I only found this folio of Matthew Leifer online](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:o1hds58nDm8J:fqxi.org/community/articles/download/__details/Leifer_Matthew.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESj9cyNbLwJLZVZ4zYyTI9ohiARG0zWvPYSW4zpQByfS29aEFsB5mNsNU6iCLUZ39mGnmjPHaCr7HQ_F_7yjeLubYjOO3oenyVwdlZJnOFxyKD8-gtVxYfIHVg1i5FnQQFaG785W&sig=AHIEtbQVd1Cbi1tEomY1MKXBp_ZpdA-HyA).

Background:

[image]

[Laurence Kirby's homepage talks the following algorithm to solve the Hydra game](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lkirby/accessible_independence_results.pdf).

> An algorithm for T is as follows: starting from the root, we travel
>   "up" the tree in such a way that, having reached a node, we travel to
>   the node immediately above it which has minimal assigned ordinal among
>   all the nodes immediately above it. (If more than one of them has
>   minimal ordinal we choose, say, the leftmost.) Eventually we reach a
>   top node and the head it is attached to is the one to chop off.

Or as Andrej Bauer writes:

> Here is a surprising fact:
>
> Theorem 1: You cannot lose!
>
> The proof uses ordinal numbers. To each hydra we assign an ordinal
>   number:
>
> A head gets the number $0$.
>   Suppose a node $x$ has sub-hydras $H_1, \ldots, H_n$ growing from it. To each sub-hydra we assign its ordinal recursively and order the
>   ordinals in descending order: $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq \ldots \geq
> > \alpha_n$. The ordinal assigned to the node $x$ is $\omega^{\alpha_1}
> > + \omega^{\alpha_2} + \cdots + \omega^{\alpha_n}$. For example, the ordinal corresponding to the hydra from the first picture above is
>   $\omega^{\omega^3 + 1} + 1$. The hydra in the second picture gets the
>   ordinal $\omega^{\omega^2 \cdot 4 + 1} + 1$.
>       By chopping off a head we strictly decrease the ordinal. Because there are no infinite strictly descending sequences of ordinals, the
>   hydra will eventually die, no matter how you chop off heads.

Comment: I am trying to understand the property of [Goodstein function](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scielo.org.co%2Fpdf%2Frcm%2Fv41n2%2Fv41n2a08.pdf&ei=bxQGUdGXLKKoiQLl4IHwAw&usg=AFQjCNF8TRP6Ay55gvbs7LzVg41X0OrXwg&sig2=o_qzoYqEVsFa-h4Ej4nb-g&bvm=bv.41524429,d.cGE). I understand it's a total function, but does it make sense to be a choice function?

Comment: A choice function starts with a set $A$ of nonempty sets, and for each $a\in A$ picks an $x\in a$. How does Goodstein function relate to this?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I deleted the first part.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure what you have in mind for the quantum game, though there are some interesting variants that perhaps capture some of what you would like, and are proof-theoretically more demanding. See for example http://www.madore.org/~david/math/hydra.xhtml and the work of Buchholz.

Comment: (By the way, other than a metaphor, there is nothing in common between what is discussed in the link you suggest, and the Hydra game of Kirby and *Paris*.)

Answer (score 1):

The probabilistic hydra game has to converge to dead hydra for the same reason, but because of the extremely long possible game play, I would guess that in any reasonable formalization, random variables that measure the length of the game (if provably a function of the gameplay, in Peano arithmetic) do not have finite expected value.